# What is the current status of the Koenig Brothers and their bases?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In Marvel's Agents of SHIELD, Fury apparently left several secret bases under the charge of a Koenig "brother" who may or may not be

> Life-Model Decoys (LMDs), aka androids.

Each brother is responsible for maintaining one of these bases, as well as the secret programs of Director Fury.

Given the current events of AoS, with two different factions of SHIELD vying for control and/or official recognition, **what is the current status of the Koenig Brothers and their bases**?

Obviously, having access to both the secret bases AND the secrets of Nick Fury would be a huge asset to either side, yet AFAIK there's been no mention of either since the "Two SHIELDs" story arc started several episodes back.

Given that Director Fury

> expressly told the Koenigs to recognize Coulson as the new Director,

it seems fairly obvious which side they would choose if given the choice.

Comment: I saw the credit listing for one of the upcoming episodes, and Oswalt was credited. We should get an answer on this soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As we see in "Scars", the 20th episode of *Agents of SHIELD* season 2, at least one of the Koenig brothers has been overseeing the maintenance of a SHIELD helicarrier, and remains loyal to <strike>Agent</strike> Director Coulson.

> This helicarrier is later used by Nick Fury in order to help evacuate Sokovia in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

Interestingly, we see whichever of the Koening brother we are following perform his morning routine at the start of this episode, in which he rips a post-it note off his mirror. The text on this note is some variation of "Call your sister" - maybe implying that the Koening brothers are human, not LMD's.

Answer (score 2):

The Koenig brothers returned in the season four episode "[Hot Potato Soup](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Hot_Potato_Soup)."

The episode doesn't really explain where they've been, but their long absence is [lampshaded](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiT2ICTiMPWAhVW5GMKHdfZDQoQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftvtropes.org%2Fpmwiki%2Fpmwiki.php%2FMain%2FLampshadeHanging&usg=AFQjCNH9xB3FYJh1zCFk5F76Sb1FOV6llw).

> ...kidnapping a Koenig? That's like catching moonlight. We can't even find them half the time.